# How to add css in custom module using layout file in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, css

I wan't to add bootstrap.css to a template in a custom layout.xml, this is my code:

view/frontend/web/css/bootstrap.css here is the css file

view/frontend/layout/pakke_trackshipment_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

  <head>
   <!-- Here I have tried both methods but no one worked -->
    <css src="Vendor_Pakke::css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
  </head>

    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Pakke\Block\TrackInfo\TrackingInfo" name="tracking_info" template="Vendor_Pakke::track_info.phtml"/>
        <!--Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template-->
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Also I will add my controller code in case i'ts wrong. I'm practically sending `$order_id` to the template and printing the template.

```
public function execute()
{

   $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("order_id");

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(' heading '));

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('tracking_info')
            ->setOrderId($order_id)
            ->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
}
```

The template shows the html correctly with the data that I'm passing to it, but the css never loads, it's just plain html.

Greetings!

Comment: please check update answer. if not works let me know.

Comment: share your module file structure. ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Make sure your layout file is correct way, otherwise not works!

Please try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <head>
   <!-- Here I have tried both methods but no one worked -->
    <css src="Vendor_Pakke::css/bootstrap.css"/>
  </head>
  <!-- put here your another code -->
</page>
```

and your file view/frontend/web/css/bootstrap.css   here ok
after this please run below commands

1. php bin/magento c:c
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
4. php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Hope it works.

Comment: Hello, It did not work anyway, but I give you the point because I now this way it would work, the problem might be in my controller, when I do the toHtml(); method

Comment: okay thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this file **pakke_trackshipment_info.xml**

you can create

**default.xml**

on **view/frontend/layout/**

so full path

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

code will be

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="VendorName_ ModuleName::css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: the problem with this way, is that It will add bootstrap to the whole website, I just wan't to add boostrap to an specific phtml, even if I don't use bootstrap classes it changes general elements like th, tr, h1, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Please Add css in your layout as per below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="VendorName_ModuleName::css/custom.css" />
  </head>
```

Now put your css in below path:

> VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css

-Remove the pub/static folder from your root directory

Use Command:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

**Just Follow Below Step :-**

> rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
>   pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache
>   var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session
>   generated/code
>
> php/bin magento s:up
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

**After Below Step Give Proper Permision.**